# Grails 2.3 - run-app not working

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am getting error while running my Grails app.

My application working in Grails 2.1.4.

I am using

```
Groovy 2.1.*
Java 1.7
Tomcat 7.0.37
```

I upgraded my application from Grails 2.1.4 to 2.3.0.M1. After I am getting some error like this:

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.0.M1
| Configuring classpath
| Error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/testuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/grails-plugin-log4j/2.3.0.M1/grails-plugin-log4j-2.3.0.M1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/testuser/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
| Error SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 143 source files.
Copying properties file...
| Compiling 143 source files.....
Updated web.xml for session information
| Running Grails application
/mycompany/dev/testuser/ws2/myapp\..\sub-app\deploy\dev\log4j.xml
| Running Grails application.
| Error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/testuser/.m2/repository/org/grails/grails-plugin-log4j/2.3.0.M1/grails-plugin-log4j-2.3.0.M1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/testuser/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
| Error SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/myapp
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: myapp.RefreshCustomerMatrixJob
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: myapp.RefreshCustomerMatrixJob
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myapp.RefreshCustomerMatrixJob
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    ... 5 more
Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: myapp.RefreshCustomerMatrixJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: myapp.RefreshCustomerMatrixJob
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: myapp.RefreshCustomerMatrixJob
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myapp.RefreshCustomerMatrixJob
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    ... 5 more
| Error Exception in thread "Thread-7" 
| Error java.lang.RuntimeException: Forked Grails VM exited with error
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess$_attachOutputListener_closure5.doCall(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy:220)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess$_attachOutputListener_closure5.doCall(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess.attachOutputListener(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy:228)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.attachOutputListener(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess.attachOutputListener(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.attachOutputListener(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess.fork(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy:172)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.fork(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess.fork(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy:141)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.fork(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer$_startSecure_closure1.doCall(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy:122)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer$_startSecure_closure1.doCall(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer$_startSecure_closure1.call(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer$_startSecure_closure1.call(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:492)
| Error     at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer$_startSecure_closure1.run(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: it cannot find `myapp.RefreshCustomerMatrixJob`

Comment: In my workspace there is no such a file. Any other suggestions please.

Comment: It's cause of error, not a suggestion. You've configured app to use bean with this class name

Comment: Still there is no solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have answered to a similar question at [How to migrate Grails 2.1 to Grails 2.3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16816980/166062) . As a summary, compare `Config.groovy` & `BuildConfig.groovy` to the default versions of a new Grails 2.3 app. Make sure your dependencies are in `BuildConfig.groovy` instead of `application.properties` and that **Tomcat**, **Hibernate** and **Scaffolding** plugins are correct version and have correct scope (build for **Tomcat plugin**, runtime for **Hibernate**).

Answer (score 1):

I saw this line in the error log :

```
Error Exception in thread "Thread-7" 
| Error java.lang.RuntimeException: Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Try to comment-out section **grails.project.fork** of **BuildConfig.groovy**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and the problem was a letter case difference between the file name and the class name in the code. Make sure your class name and file name match exactly.

For instance I had my file name as OAuthCallBackController.groovy and the class name as OauthCallBackController (notice the lower case 'a')